# NumPy reading/writing to file performance (specifically ndarray.tofile)

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy

I decided to compare the performance of NumPy's `ndarray.tofile` versus the standard `f.write` and I was surprised by what the results appear to be. Why is `tofile` ~30x slower than the normal file writing? Is `tofile`'s performance better than `f.write` on huge datasets?

**WRITE:**

**ndarray.tofile(file): 10.668 secs**

```
timeit.timeit("a.tofile(f)", "import numpy as np; dt=np.dtype('B'); f=open('test.x','wb'); a=np.array(range(100),dt)")
```

**write | file.write(ndarray.tobytes()): 0.316 secs**

```
timeit.timeit("f.write(a.tobytes())", "import numpy as np; dt=np.dtype('B'); f=open('test.x','wb'); a=np.array(range(100),dt)")
```

**READ:**

**np.array(list(f.read()), dt): 11.544 secs**

```
timeit.timeit("a=np.array(list(f.read()),dt)", "import numpy as np; dt=np.dtype('B'); f=open('test.x','rb');")
```

**np.fromfile(f, dt): 11.544 secs**

```
timeit.timeit("a=np.fromfile(f,dt)", "import numpy as np; dt=np.dtype('B'); f=open('test.x','rb');")
```

Comment: I have `0.225 s` with `tofile` and `0.348 s` with `write`

Comment: by reading the source code of `tofile()`, it duplicates the file handle, calls `flush()` to write the data to disk. but `f.write()` will cache the data in memory.

Comment: @filippo did you use the same command? I'm using Anaconda / Python 3.6.4 / Windows 10

Comment: @DarkMatterMatt I missed the `3.x` tag. I can reproduce similar results as yours on `3.6.3` while `tofile` is slightly faster on `2.7.14` (same numpy version, `1.14.3`)